# Publishing mathematics research(which I believe is already there)

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, publishing

I am a class 12th student, and over the past year have researched quite a lot on sequences and series, and developed a formula to predict :

1. The n-th term of a series
2. The sum to n terms of the series
3. Arthimetic and Geometric means of the series
4. And the proof of all the above

After all this was formulated, and I hadn't found yet that this formula was there or not, I wanted to send it for publishing to a journal, and still want to do so.

But:

When I was wandering a day on stackexchange when I saw several questions being solved using the same formula. On further investigation, I found that the formula I had developed was called Binomial Transforms(or more correctly its inverse). 
Can I still send it for publishing, alongwith all other small things, and showing how to implement it to sequences and series, provided I give them the derivation of the formula(to show **I** have developed it too), or anything else can I do about it?

Comment: You can try it in some beginners journals where publication cost is free.

Comment: Do not try to publish this. Math journals are generally for original research.  Most mathematicians do not publish anything until graduate school or (sometimes) late years of undergrad.  To publish work, you need to be very, very familiar with the established material and justify how your work adds to it.

Comment: Good work on the re-discovery.  As you will have learned by now, that's a fairly well covered topic though fresh applications are always welcome.  Don't worry about covering old ground....there's really no way to avoid it as you are learning the subject. I suggest moving on to the next project.  Eventually you'll get a teacher or mentor who will help steer you to fresh results.

Comment: You are only allowed to publish if something is new about what you are publishing. Sometimes you can publish known results if your method of deriving them is novel in an interesting way. Mathematicians are not like school teachers who will read the same solutions to the same test questions every year so that they can evaluate their students, instead they are themselves like students who read papers to learn things they didn't already know.

Comment: That said - congrats on developing this all independently!  If you do want to write it up, you might consider a blog - although it may be difficult to attract readers.  I'd also invite you to contribute any interesting sequences to OEIS if they are not there - later researchers coming across the sequences may appreciate it.  You could even include links to a writeup.

Comment: Publishing is of course something one can pay to have done, and it is commendable that (with a little Web searching) you were able to find out your discovery is not original.  It isn't really a topic for Math.SE to advise on the business mechanics of publication, but non-original findings are often published as *expository articles*.  A good explanation of a formula and its history may prove helpful to other students of mathematics.  This is the nature of most posting here on Math.SE.   Perhaps you will find a Question that can be answered using your formula, and that would likely be fun.

Comment: By the way—don't let the fact that your discovery turned out to not be (historically) original put you off going and exploring and deriving even more things yourself. It's very good practice and you should be proud that you are able to do something creative that goes beyond just completing exercises and homework. Don't stop! (although you probably don't need much encouragement)

Comment: If you want, you can give some examples of your results for nice sequences in [the OEIS](https://oeis.org) and then submit it to the [Journal of Integer Sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_of_Integer_Sequences).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).